# qgis join attributes by location - options

Tags: join, location, qgis

when joining attributes by location there are a multitude of options to tick:

- intersects
- overlaps
- contains
- within
- equals
- crosses
- touches

There is no documentation available. 
Where could I find information, what each of these options means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This links explains the spatial relationships defined by the Open Geospatial Consortium:

[https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/spatialrelations.htm][1]

This should help you.

Comment: thanks, that is indeed helpful! The link without brackets: 
https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/spatialrelations.htm

Answer (score 0):

The link in the accepted answer gives a 404, use the version in the comment.

Alternatively, [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/305193/65021) on GIS stack exchange also gives a great overview of the differences specific to QGIS.